# I came across this fun pattern, can anyone give me a proof for this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**The Pattern**

$\begin{align*}1(8)&=(3^2)-1\\
2(8)&= (3+1)^2 \\
3(8)&= (3+2)^2-1\\
4(8)&= (3+3)^2 - 4\\
5(8)&= (3+4)^2- 9\\
6(8)&= (3+5)^2-16\end{align*}$

**Conjecture**

I think the pattern is that the numbers appear in the following form:

$$8(n+1) = (3+n)^2 - (n-1)^2$$

Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not really that good at math.

Comment: Do you mean $(3+n)^2-(n-1)^2$ which is equal to $8(n+1)$ ?

Comment: @MatthewTowers thanks, will do

Comment: $(3+n)^2-(n-1)^2=8(n+1)$

Comment: @Peter yes. couldnt see that because my notebook was filled with scribbles

Comment: Plug $n$ in the previous formula I mention you will find the reason why? It's actually an identity

Comment: Just expand the squares using the binomial formula and simplify

Comment: For what its worth, this is not a result of number theory but rather is a result of highschool algebra.

Comment: @JMoravitz Im a freshman :)

Comment: @JMoravitz  "Everything is number theory" -- Pal Erdös.

Comment: Congratulations on your discovery. That said, before you ask a question here you should rewrite the scribbles in your notebook on a new clean page. Then think about how to understand the pattern you observed. See if anything you already know (like ordinary algebra) helps.

Comment: @SatvikShubh: Your (fixed) identity is true. Congratulations on observing and describing a pattern! That's what mathematics is all about. Keep it up!

Comment: @EthanBolker Thank you. I find disorganized notes more helpful (idrk why) but yeah ill present it to my teachers/math department in a neater way

Comment: @SatvikShubh You always _start_ disorganized. Then you learn more when you clean it up.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just learning algebra, this might not be obvious.  But, the rule to keep in mind is that multiplication distributes over addition.  On the left-hand side, you have $8(n+1)$ which after distribution equals $8n+8.$  Now we have to show that the right-hand side gives the same thing.

Let's work out the two terms one at a time.

$(n+3)^2 = (n+3)(n+3) = n(n+3) + 3(n+3) = n^2 + 3n + 3n+9 = 
n^2+6n+9$

$(n-1)^2 = (n-1)(n-1) = n(n-1) + (-1)(n-3) = n^2  - n - n +1 = n^2-2n+1$

$(n+3)^2 - (n-1)^2 = (n^2+3n+9)-(n^2-2n+1) = n^2+6n+9 - n^2+2n-1 = 8n+8$

As required.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yup. asked my teacher and she said the same thing. Thanks!